# Assigning/retrieving methods not working in separate chaining Python hash map

Tags: python, hashmap

Though I know Python has the built-in dictionary for practical purposes, I'm trying to understand the concept of separate chaining hash maps by creating one with flowers and their definitions.

When I try to print a retrieval from the hash map, though, I get `None`.

```
from linked_list import Node, LinkedList

class HashMap:
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.array_size = size
    self.array = [LinkedList() for i in range(size)]

  def hash(self, key):
    return sum(key.encode())

  def compress(self, hash_code):
    return hash_code % self.array_size

  def assign(self, key, value):
    hash_code = self.hash(key)
    array_index = self.compress(hash_code)
    payload = Node([key, value])
    list_at_array = self.array[array_index]
    for item in list_at_array:
      if key == item[0]:
        item[1] = value
      else:
        self.array[array_index].insert(payload)

  def retrieve(self, key):
    hash_code = self.hash(key)
    array_index = self.compress(hash_code)
    list_at_index = self.array[array_index]
    for item in list_at_index:
      if item[0] == key:
        return item[1]
      else:
        return None

from blossom_lib import flower_definitions

blossom = HashMap(len(flower_definitions))

for each in flower_definitions:
  blossom.assign(each[0], each[1])
print(blossom.retrieve('daisy'))
```

Here are the two modules:

blossom_lib.py

```
flower_definitions = [['begonia', 'cautiousness'], ['chrysanthemum', 'cheerfulness'], ['carnation', 'memories'], ['daisy', 'innocence'], ['hyacinth', 'playfulness'], ['lavender', 'devotion'], ['magnolia', 'dignity'], ['morning glory', 'unrequited love'], ['periwinkle', 'new friendship'], ['poppy', 'rest'], ['rose', 'love'], ['snapdragon', 'grace'], ['sunflower', 'longevity'], ['wisteria', 'good luck']]
```

linked_list.py

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def get_value(self):
    return self.value

  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node

  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, head_node=None):
    self.head_node = head_node

  def insert(self, new_node):
    current_node = self.head_node

    if not current_node:
      self.head_node = new_node

    while(current_node):
      next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
      if not next_node:
        current_node.set_next_node(new_node)

  def __iter__(self):
    current_node = self.head_node
    while(current_node):
      yield current_node.get_value()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

1) `Node` initialisation of `next_node` - resulting in AttributeError

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = None
```

2) `LinkedList` iteration - 
`current_node` variable controlling the loop was never moved to the next element in the list.

```
def __iter__(self):
    current_node = self.head_node
    while (current_node):
        value = current_node.get_value()
        current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
        yield value
```

3) `LinkedList` `insert` - similarly like in the previous case, `current_node` was never moved to the next element in the list.

```
while (current_node):
    next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    if not next_node:
        current_node.set_next_node(new_node)
    current_node = next_node
```

4) `HashMap` `assign` - it was overcomplicated, after identifying the correct list to place it in, it is enough to use the `insert` method of that list.

```
def assign(self, key, value):
    hash_code = self.hash(key)
    array_index = self.compress(hash_code)
    payload = Node([key, value])
    list_at_array = self.array[array_index]
    list_at_array.insert(payload)
```

5) `HashMap` `retrieve` - it would return None if the list had multiple elements (with the same hash value) and the first element was not the one that we were looking for. The correct approach is to return `None` after iterating through all the elements in the list, and if the element is not found then `None` is returned, so the fix is to decrease the indentation of `return None`.

```
def retrieve(self, key):
    hash_code = self.hash(key)
    array_index = self.compress(hash_code)
    list_at_index = self.array[array_index]
    for item in list_at_index:
        if item[0] == key:
            return item[1]
    return None
```

Checking the correctness for your example using:

```
for each in flower_definitions:
    print(each[0] + ' (' + str(sum(each[0].encode()) % len(flower_definitions)) + '): ' + blossom.retrieve(each[0]))
```

Gives:

```
begonia (11): cautiousness
chrysanthemum (2): cheerfulness
carnation (7): memories
daisy (6): innocence
hyacinth (2): playfulness
lavender (9): devotion
magnolia (0): dignity
morning glory (7): unrequited love
periwinkle (4): new friendship
poppy (8): rest
rose (7): love
snapdragon (5): grace
sunflower (3): longevity
wisteria (4): good luck
```

The complete solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/krzysztof-slowinski/578e9806739a4f04c9f39b3ac024eacd)